# Magento2: How can I apply shipping cart rules?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, shopping-cart-price-rules

I want add shipping method on subtotal. If subtotal equal or greater $250 Shipping method should be Free and If less $250 Shipping method should be Flat Rate.

Any one help in this?

[image]

I have applied shipping cart rules but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from `Admin > Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > Free Shipping`.

You just have to enable this method and fill "Minimum Order Amount".

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I want add shipping method on subtotal. If subtotal equal or greater $250 Shipping method should be Free and If less $250 Shipping method should be Flat Rate.